# Adding Duplicated Sums MySQL Joins

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate-functions

I have a query joining several tables and I am pulling in some duplicate values in the `SUM`.

I have tried using some

```
SELECT 
    po.vendor AS 'Factory', 
    po.doc AS 'PO#', 
    po.date AS 'Date Ordered', 
    po.due_by AS 'Est. Receive Date',
    po.status AS 'PO Status', 
    po.amount AS 'PO Total Amount', 
    ROUND(SUM(IF(b.status = 'Paid In Full', b.amount, '')),2) 'Amount Paid To PO',
    ROUND(SUM(IF(b.status != 'Paid In Full',b.amount, '')),2) 'Amount Billed But Not Payed',
    SUM(IFNULL(so.amount, 0)) as 'SO Amount Cont. Cust.',
    so.doc,
    SUM(IFNULL(d.amount, 0)) as 'Deposits on SO',
    SUM(IFNULL(i.amount, 0)) as 'Amount Invoiced Cont. Cust.',
    SUM(IFNULL(i.amount_remain, 0)) as 'Amount Remaining from Customer'

FROM po 

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT bill.doc, bill.amount, bill.po_fk, bill.status FROM bill GROUP BY bill.doc) b
        ON concat('Purchase Order #', po.doc) = b.po_fk


    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT so.doc, so.amount FROM so GROUP BY so.doc) so 
        ON concat('Sales Order #', so.doc) = po.so_fk

    LEFT JOIN  
        (SELECT deposit.doc, deposit.amount, deposit.status, deposit.so_fk FROM deposit GROUP BY deposit.doc) d
        ON concat('Sales Order #', so.doc) = d.so_fk

    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT invoice.doc, invoice.amount, invoice.so_fk, invoice.amount_remain FROM invoice GROUP BY invoice.doc) i
        ON concat('Sales Order #', so.doc) = i.so_fk

    GROUP BY po.doc;
```

Here is some of the results

```
+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+
| PO#                       | PO Total Amount | Amount Paid To PO | SO Amount Cont. Cust. | doc     | Deposits on SO | Amount Invoiced Cont. Cust. | Amount Remaining from Customer |
+---------------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------+----------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------+
| 12734-I,12736-I           |        53452.55 |              0.00 |              63931.16 | SO28292 |       34715.58 |                        0.00 |                           0.00 |
| 13303-I/13304-I           |        44080.29 |          88160.58 |             209554.44 | SO19842 |      118013.08 |                   112777.22 |                           0.00 |
| 160512JB-5                |         1095.00 |              0.00 |                  0.00 | NULL    |           0.00 |                        0.00 |                           0.00 |
| 160713JB-2                |          163.00 |            163.00 |                  0.00 | NULL    |           0.00 |                        0.00 |                           0.00 |
| 161103 MYA FLYOVER        |          937.52 |            870.05 |                349.87 | SO26797 |        1099.87 |                     1099.87 |                           0.00 |
| 161228-RG Assembly Blocks |          864.00 |            864.00 |                  0.00 | NULL    |           0.00 |                        0.00 |                           0.00 |
| 1852998                   |        39207.10 |          39207.10 |              51542.57 | SO19688 |           0.00 |                    51542.57 |                           0.00 |
| 1955463                   |        39327.21 |          39327.21 |              51664.96 | SO22327 |           0.00 |                    51664.96 |                           0.00 |
| 1957583                   |        35591.61 |          35591.61 |              47235.91 | SO22414 |           0.00 |                    47235.91 |                           0.00 |
| 1988860                   |        36373.72 |          34455.52 |              48356.20 | SO23363 |           0.00 |                    48356.20 |                           0.00 |
| 2068548                   |        36284.97 |          72569.94 |             192776.28 | SO25250 |           0.00 |                    96388.14 |                           0.00 |
| 2084384                   |        54111.82 |         108223.64 |             286526.04 | SO25651 |           0.00 |                   143263.02 |                           0.00 |
| 2084510                   |        54829.71 |         109659.42 |             289017.28 | SO25658 |           0.00 |                   144508.64 |                           0.00 |
| 2219389                   |        39066.53 |              0.00 |              51693.99 | SO29601 |           0.00 |                        0.00 |                           0.00 |
| 2219407                   |           34.70 |              0.00 |                  0.00 | NULL    |           0.00 |                        0.00 |                           0.00 |
```

And then just to validate that it is adding the value duplicate times.  You can see the 13th row about on SO25658 is showing the `SUM(IFNULL(so.amount, 0)) as 'SO Amount Cont. Cust.',` with a value of `289017.28`

```
mysql> select * from so where doc= 'SO25658';
+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+
| id     | doc     | status | date    | amount   |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+
| 230632 | SO25658 | Billed | 10/7/16 | 72254.32 |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Just to sum up in one sentence,  how can I ensure that I am removing duplicate values from query with multiple `JOINS`?

Thanks!

Comment: Sum in a subquery before you join grouping by the joined values.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @xQbert